# Where would the buttons go best?

Tags: gui-design, buttons

I made a browser app, and have gotten some positive feedback, and someone asked if I could put buttons on it.

It is located here: https://freezephoenix.github.io/FireSnake/3D.html

Background: You use the right and left arrow keys to control the snake.
 However, there are no arrow keys on mobile, I would like to add buttons to the game. 
I was wondering where they would go best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this game is to be played in landscape, it seems like the obvious place to put these buttons is to the left and right of the left and right vertical red lines (you seem to already use those spaces to give feedback as to which button is pressed on the keyboard). The buttons themselves could be semi-transparent so they don't completely obscure the view of the game space in those areas.

[image]

As an alternative, have you considered the possibility of using either tilt or swipe gestures on mobile devices instead of buttons?

Comment: I have considered swipe, but not tilt. Also, it would be hard to swipe that fast. Unfortunately that is not feedback, but those lines are the outline of the snake, and when you turn, you see your body. *But* If you see it that way, then you can make that connection - making those sensible places to put the buttons.